# mongo installation and data in different locations

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I installed mongodb in `usr/local/mongodb` but my data is in my project directory `desktop/root/data/db`

I want to use mongo shell to look at my data. If I run `usr/local/mongdb/bin/mongo` will this show me the data in my `project/data/db` directory? or is there some command I need to run with `.../bin/mongo` to tell it where my data is?

I tried `--dbpath` but that didn't work

Comment: You need to start `mongod` server with `--dbpath=...desktop/root/data/db`. `mongo` shell only connects to your server.

Comment: i see, thanks for the info